# fast method to run game logic on server

Tags: applet

For security purposes I want to source out some logic parts of the game out onto the server.

For example (Java Applet):
I have a player that shoots items to get points. For each successfull shoot, there will be called a function on the server that checks if it was legal and how many points the player gets and adds them to the total points. Total points are kept on server and a copy of actual total points is sent to the applet for displaying.

Now my questions:

1. I want to use a php script for the server side operations. Are there faster solutions?!
2. How can I handle this for each user that plays this game. For each request, there must be a new thread (which will already be handled by apache webserver) and I save the total points to a SESSION variable until the game is over.?!

Thanks!

regards matthais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a PHP script from within Apache might not be the best performing/scalable solution, but it may be a quick way set up and test your game.

Be aware that with HTTP you open a new connection every time you send a request to the server. This is a serious overhead! (**EDIT**: sorry, got mixed up here, since HTTP 1.1 persistent connection is the default. But there is still an overhead for each HTTP request!)

Maybe you want to create your own server listening on some TCP port (in any language of your preference). Of course, you'd have to implement the security layer on your own (or include a third party library).

This actually boils down to a question of urgency and available resources.

**EDIT**

For your question #2: Using PHP session variables sure is a good approach (but maybe not scalable). Otherwise, saving data as cookies may be a second possibility, but may be prone to manipulation again.

Comment: Ok thx!! So what would be a more efficient solution? So I will use HTTP as long as there are no performance problems.

Comment: @MatthiasReisner: I don't know about your programming skills with the different languages, but here (http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/) is a simple tutorial for a TCP Client/Server connection.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to run an application server. I only want to have the apache web server.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. In that case you'd go best with Apache+PHP which handles the connection to the client, but as a drawback, you'll always have the HTTP stack overhead.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to specify a custom lightweight Transport Protocol in my case?

Comment: Apache is per definition an HTTP(S) server. If you want to implement a different protocol, you'd have to take another option, e.g a custom server like in the link I sent you.